# How to nest templates

Tags: xslt

I have an XSLT file with several, reusable, templates that assemble a table. I want to use and nest these templates within the XSLT in my body. Something like this:

```
<xsl:call-template name="Table1">
  <xsl:call-template name="Table2">
    // Additional Code here!
  </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:call-template>
```

The purpose behind this is that I assemble the table like individual building blocks. For example, if I have two tables swapped out into two templates, I want to decide whether to call these two tables separately or call them so that they are nested.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how this works because my IDE tells me that the same call "xsl:call-template" cannot be a child of "xsl:call-template".

What options and possibilities do I have?

Using call-template, apply-template

Comment: Perhaps flesh out your input and the wanted output and the template bodies, then show us one example where both templates work for one of your requirements "to assemble a table" and then show us what kind of other table you want to create where you think nesting call-template would help. Also tag your question with the version of XSLT you use as (more in the context of apply-templates than call-template) XSLT 2 and later have e.g. `xsl:next-match`.

Answer (score 0):

Your IDE is correct: the only content that can be placed inside of a `xsl:call-template` element is `xsl:with-param`.

https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#element-call-template.

If your intention is to execute conditionally a template B from within a template A, you can do something like this very contrived example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">

  <xsl:output indent="yes" />
  
  <xsl:variable name="current-day-of-month" as="xs:integer"
                select="day-from-date(current-date())" />

  <xsl:template match="/" name="xsl:initial-template">
    <xsl:call-template name="Table1" />
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="Table1" >
    <tbl>
      <ths><th>header1</th><th>header2</th><th>header3</th></ths>
        <trs><tr>today</tr><tr>is</tr><tr>{$current-day-of-month}</tr></trs>
        <xsl:if test="$current-day-of-month eq 22" >
          <xsl:call-template name="Table2" />
        </xsl:if>

    </tbl>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template name="Table2" >
    <trs><tr>special</tr><tr>for</tr><tr>22nd</tr></trs>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```